# Is it feasible to connect mobile and web clients directly to kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a usecase where I have to collect user events and store it in Kafka. Is it efficient to directly use Kafka clients in mobile apps and websites to produce messages directly to Kafka instead of a middle layer. Is Kafka designed to handle millions of concurrent connections?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Technically you can do it. The main reason people do not do it, especially for mobile apps, is that it would rather be difficult to maintain a long-term evolution of the product, control its security or even its scale.

In the past years, Kafka Clients API has evolved dramatically (for the best but, it's still a change). It also includes authorization and authentication mechanisms, but there's not much freedom on what you can do with those. Kafka is not built upon a standardized protocol and technology-agnostic specification like JMS that could be thought as a bit more flexible.

Also, between major versions, compatibility is not guaranteed, as for most existing technologies. It may happen that you need to keep multiple server versions for a long time just because some mobile clients are still outdated and there's coupling to a specific client version, that itself is coupled to a specific server version.

On the other side and for the same reason, it could also happen that you would need to keep handling older versions of the messages schemas for a long time, just to keep older clients happy.

That's when HTTP and, more specifically, the [API gateway pattern](https://microservices.io/patterns/apigateway.html), comes into place.

HTTP APIs are easier to throttle, perform rate limiting, applying custom security policies, custom authentication/authorization strategies, etc. And they are based on a standard protocol that's used all over the Internet.

There are also advantages of using HTTP when you plan to have some partner integrations using your backend platform. As they can do it easily without changing the technology stack.

By not exposing Kafka to the outside clients, you can change the underlying technology stack later without impacting the clients. To be honest, although Kafka is a brilliant piece of technology, it's difficult to compete with HTTP for internet communication. Kafka actually provides a [REST Proxy](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka-rest/docs/index.html), an HTTP based client that could be possibly thought to be used for this sort of things.